# Accessing properties of an object in a function which is inside of that object

Tags: javascript, object

This is just a bit of a nonsense example but it perfectly describes my problem.

The following call of the object's function gives `undefined` for `bird` property:

```
const birds = {
 species:['Grey tinamou','Greater rhea','Dwarf cassowary'],
 bird: 'Bird',
 summary: function(){
  return this.species.map(function(species) {
   return `${species} is a ${this.bird}`;
  });
 }
};

birds.summary();
```

1) How can I access the `bird` property in the object's function?

2.1) Can I do this without passing in the `bird` property's value itself?

Like this: `birds.summary(birds.bird);`

2.2) is there a better/another way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a regular function, `this` is the object from which the function is called. If you call `birds.func()`, then inside this function `this === birds`. If the function is called just like `func()`, then the context will be `window` (`undefined` in strict mode). In the callback function that you passed to map, `this` is `window` or `undefined`. The arrow function works differently - it inherits `this` from the context where it is declared.

Use () => {} for inherit `this` from function `summary`:

```
this.species.map((species) => {...
```

And read about [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sorry for bothering but will the article help me to answer the question - why the `bird` property is accessible inside of an arrow function and not with a regular function?

Comment: I know the Russian language if that's what you are asking.

Comment: @VitalyPlatonov Да, в этой статье есть вся необходимая информация, но если коротко, то в обычной функции `this` - объект, от которого вызвана функция. То есть если вы вызываете birds.func(), то внутри этой функции `this === birds`. Если функция вызвана просто как func(), то контекстом будет window (или другое, в зависимости откуда вызвана функция). В функции коллбэка, которую вы передали в map, `this` равен `undefined`. Стрелочная функция работает иначе - она наследует this из того контекста, где она объявлена.

Comment: чуть наврал, в коллбэке this будет равен window, если не включен strict mode

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer! I'll go through the article and edit your answer a bit later so other people can benefit from this (link to the article may get broken). If you do that ahead of me - let me know I will mark it as accepted then, thanks.